# Paperclip 'has contents that are not what they are reported to be' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to make uploading movie files possible. In that purpose i installed Paperclip gem. My movie class looks like this:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :movie_file,
    styles: lambda { |a| a.instance.is_image? ? {:small => "x200>", :medium => "x300>", :large => "x400>"}  : {:thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'mkv', :time => 10}, :medium => { :geometry => "300x300#", :format => 'mkv', :time => 10}}},
    processors: lambda { |a| a.is_video? ? [ :ffmpeg ] : [ :thumbnail ] }


  validates_attachment :movie_file, presence: true,
  content_type: { content_type: "movie/mkv" }
```

Yet with every upload attempt i get `has contents that are not what they are reported to be` error. How can i get around that?

UPDATE:

Full error is 'Validation failed: Movie file has contents that are not what they are reported to be, Movie file is invalid, Movie file content type is invalid'

Stacktrace only leads to `save!` method:

```
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:21:in `block in create'
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:20:in `create'
```

Comment: Can you paste the error in the post please ? full stacktrace

Comment: Are you sure your uploaded files content type is `"movie/mkv"` ?

Comment: what i upload is cinematic trailer, mkv format, i'm 100% sure

Comment: can you show me your code  anything..? may be little debugging will help to solve this.

Comment: what code do you want to see? whole app?